# Set Attribute No Longer Working on Shopify Site

Tags: javascript, shopify

I created a script that makes it so that an ID gets added to an element if it is visible on the page. If the element isn't visible, it keeps looking for it. As of 2 months ago, it stopped working. Here is the code:

Html

```
<div class="discount-summary">
    $20 Off
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   setInterval(addDiscount, 1000)
});

function addDiscount() {
    $('.discount-summary').attr('id','discountbox');
}
```

Any insight as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Might be some changes to loading the jquery code and it stops working. you need to check and make sure jquery is loaded before your code, it depended on jquery.

Comment: It looks like you were correct. The site wasn't loading in jquery 3.4.1. I just loaded a jquery file before the theme.js and that appears to have sorted out the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This was resolved by adding a reference to a version of jQuery that was compatible with the code I created into the header of the site.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Not sure why Shopify removed it in the first place but oh well.

Comment: jQuery 3.4.1 contains css vulnerabilities which are fixed in jQuery 3.5+ - why not switch your code to not require jQuery?